# Decoding Javascript Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, deobfuscation

So I have this JavaScript code that my friend gave me and I don't know what it does and he wants me to find out. So I was reading through it then I found this.

```
localStorage[_0xa5fd[8]] = JSON[_0xa5fd[14]](default_r_o)), !d[_0xa5fd[15]](localStorage[_0xa5fd[8]])) return;
                        r_o = JSON[_0xa5fd[11]](localStorage[_0xa5fd[8]]), jQuery[_0xa5fd[39]](r_o, function (_0xb434x1, _0xb434x2) {
                            void 0 == _0xb434x2 && _0xb434x1 == _0xa5fd[16] ? _0xb434x2 == _0xa5fd[12] : void 0 == _0xb434x2 && (_0xb434x2 = !1), typeof _0xb434x2 == _0xa5fd[17] ? (jQuery(_0xa5fd[5], jQuery(_0xa5fd[18] + _0xb434x1 + _0xa5fd[19])[_0xa5fd[6]]())[0][_0xa5fd[4]] = _0xb434x2, fnc = jQuery(_0xa5fd[5], jQuery(_0xa5fd[18] + _0xb434x1 + _0xa5fd[19])[_0xa5fd[6]]())[_0xa5fd[21]](_0xa5fd[20]), fnf = _0xb434x1 == _0xa5fd[22] || _0xb434x1 == _0xa5fd[23] ? _0xa5fd[24] : _0xa5fd[13], fnc = fnc[_0xa5fd[27]](0, fnc[_0xa5fd[26]](_0xa5fd[25])) + _0xa5fd[25] + fnf + _0xb434x2 + _0xa5fd[28], eval(_0xa5fd[29] + fnc)) : _0xb434x1 == _0xa5fd[30] ? jQuery(_0xa5fd[32])[_0xa5fd[31]](r_o[_0xa5fd[30]]) : _0xb434x1 == _0xa5fd[33] ? jQuery(_0xa5fd[34])[_0xa5fd[31]](r_o[_0xa5fd[33]]) : _0xb434x1 == _0xa5fd[16] && (r_o[_0xa5fd[16]] == _0xa5fd[35] ? (jQuery(_0xa5fd[37])[_0xa5fd[36]](_0xa5fd[4])
```

What I'm asking for is there a way to expand the arrays? Such as automaticly recoding the program with the arrays turned into the words?

Comment: It's obfuscated, which means to "make obscure, unclear, or unintelligible". The intent is to prevent you from reading it, and that intent has succeeded.

Comment: I can get the words to recreate it but it would take too long. Is there a way to automatic'ly fix the arrays?

Comment: Yes, you can write a script that will replace the words.

Comment: What language should I write it in? @AlexanderPopov

Comment: @DrGoat write it in Malbolge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a js sample of such script:

```
<script>

        var _0xa5fd = [ "failure", "onload", "responseXML", "responseText", "DOMParser", "text/xml", "parseFromString", "Microsoft.XMLDOM"];

        /**
         * @param {FileList} fileList
         */
        function handleFiles(fileList)
        {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = onReadFile;
            reader.readAsText(fileList.item(0));
        }

        function onReadFile(event)
        {
            var fileContent = event.target.result;
            var regex = /_0xa5fd\[(\d+)\]/ig;
            var itemList;
            var count = 0;

            while ((itemList = regex.exec(fileContent)) != null)
            {
                var realValueKey = itemList[1];
                var realValue = _0xa5fd[realValueKey];

                if(realValue !== undefined)
                {
                    var replaceRegex = new RegExp('_0xa5fd\\[' + realValueKey + '\\]', 'g');
                    fileContent = fileContent.replace(replaceRegex, "'" + realValue + "'");
                }

                count++;
            }

            console.log('finish: ' + count);
            document.getElementById('scriptContent').innerText = fileContent;
        }
    </script>
```

and html code to select your obfuscated file:

```
<input type="file" id="input" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
<div id="scriptContent"></div>
```

Comment: Whoa thanks this is awesome! If I was to try it should I have to upload the html to a site then run the JavaScript?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question. You need to create an html page and add the code snippets I provided. Then launch the page in a browser and select the file you need to process.